# Different query plans in Postgres 8.4 and 9.4

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, sql-execution-plan

This is a simplified distillation of a more complex situation that we have in production.
The data and setup used for this test case can be found at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2I7_NGvCSVOT3ZNNWhpeFdFbTg/view?usp=sharing.

#### Background

I have two very similar dedicated virtual machines running PostgreSQL. One is running PG 8.4 and the other is running PG 9.4, but both are using nearly identical configs. There are some other differences outlined in the table below.

There are two parts to this question:

1. Why does PG 8.4 choose a much faster query plan for the *version 1* query compared to 9.4? The computed cost for both plans are similar, but the actual time spent is 10x greater in PG 9.4.
2. Why does changing the `WHERE` clause to reference a.id, instead of r.a_id modify the query plan so significantly?

#### Systems info

```
                  | PG 8.4     | PG 9.4
:---------------- | :--------- |
OS                | CentOS 5.5 | Ubuntu 14.04
RAM               | 16GB       | 16GB
CPUs              | 4 x vCPU   | 4 x vCPU
VMware VM version | 4          | 8
Disk Size         | 50GB       | 200GB
```

#### Systems benchmarks

```
                                | PG 8.4   | PG 9.4
:------------------------------ | :--------|
dd write (32GB)                 | 38 MB/s  | 277 MB/s
dd read (32GB)                  | 241 MB/s | 243 MB/s
bonnie++ 1.03 block write K/sec | 208941   | 248528
bonnie++ 1.03 block read K/sec  | 172184   | 321814
bonnie++ seek /sec              | 543.5    | 1559.8
pgbench (-s 1000, -t 2000) TPS  | 345      | 325
```

#### The queries

**version 1**
```

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT DISTINCT
    t.id
FROM
    a
INNER JOIN b --USING(a_id)
    ON b.a_id = a.id
INNER JOIN r -- USING(a_id)
    ON r.a_id = a.id
INNER JOIN t
    ON t.session_id = '1'
        AND a.inst_id = t.inst_id
        AND b.study_id = t.study_id
        AND r.q_id = t.q_id
WHERE
    r.a_id IN (1, 2, 3)
    AND (
        r.q_id in ('q1', 'q2', 'q3') OR
        r.q_id in ('q4', 'q5', 'q6') OR
        r.q_id in ('q7', 'q8', 'q9') OR
        r.q_id in ('q10', 'q11', 'q12')
    )
```

```

**version 2**
```

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT DISTINCT
    t.id
FROM
    a
INNER JOIN b --USING(a_id)
    ON b.a_id = a.id
INNER JOIN r -- USING(a_id)
    ON r.a_id = a.id
INNER JOIN t
    ON t.session_id = '1'
        AND a.inst_id = t.inst_id
        AND b.study_id = t.study_id
        AND r.q_id = t.q_id
WHERE
    a.id IN (1, 2, 3) -- << THIS IS WHAT CHANGED
    AND (
        r.q_id in ('q1', 'q2', 'q3') OR
        r.q_id in ('q4', 'q5', 'q6') OR
        r.q_id in ('q7', 'q8', 'q9') OR
        r.q_id in ('q10', 'q11', 'q12')
    )
```

```

#### Query performance

```
                | PG 8.4 | PG 9.4 |
 -------------- | ------ | ------ |
 version 1 (ms) | 0.718  | 12.355 |
 version 2 (ms) | 1.799  | 3.288  |
```

#### EXPLAIN plans

**PG 8.4, version 1**

```
"HashAggregate  (cost=63.78..63.79 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.603..0.603 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Hash Join  (cost=61.02..63.78 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.540..0.593 rows=1 loops=1)"
"        Hash Cond: ((b.a_id = a.id) AND (b.study_id = t.study_id))"
"        ->  Seq Scan on b  (cost=0.00..2.00 rows=100 width=8) (actual time=0.015..0.041 rows=100 loops=1)"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=60.99..60.99 rows=2 width=16) (actual time=0.513..0.513 rows=1 loops=1)"
"              ->  Hash Join  (cost=58.22..60.99 rows=2 width=16) (actual time=0.435..0.511 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                    Hash Cond: ((a.id = r.a_id) AND ((a.inst_id)::text = (t.inst_id)::text))"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on a  (cost=0.00..2.00 rows=100 width=6) (actual time=0.005..0.026 rows=100 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=58.13..58.13 rows=6 width=44) (actual time=0.418..0.418 rows=3 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=17.54..58.13 rows=6 width=44) (actual time=0.044..0.416 rows=3 loops=1)"
"                                Hash Cond: ((r.q_id)::text = (t.q_id)::text)"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on r  (cost=0.00..40.44 rows=23 width=7) (actual time=0.014..0.368 rows=34 loops=1)"
"                                      Filter: ((a_id = ANY ('{1,2,3}'::integer[])) AND (((q_id)::text = ANY ('{q1,q2,q3}'::text[])) OR ((q_id)::text = ANY ('{q4,q5,q6}'::text[])) OR ((q_id)::text = ANY ('{q7,q8,q9}'::text[])) OR ((q_id)::text = ANY ('{q10, (...)"
"                                ->  Hash  (cost=17.50..17.50 rows=3 width=72) (actual time=0.020..0.020 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                      ->  Seq Scan on t  (cost=0.00..17.50 rows=3 width=72) (actual time=0.006..0.016 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                            Filter: ((session_id)::text = '1'::text)"
"Total runtime: 0.718 ms"
```

**PG 8.4, version 2**

```
"HashAggregate  (cost=61.77..61.78 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1.685..1.686 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Hash Join  (cost=22.41..61.77 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.243..1.677 rows=1 loops=1)"
"        Hash Cond: (((a.inst_id)::text = (t.inst_id)::text) AND (b.study_id = t.study_id) AND ((r.q_id)::text = (t.q_id)::text))"
"        ->  Hash Join  (cost=4.85..43.94 rows=23 width=9) (actual time=0.203..1.626 rows=34 loops=1)"
"              Hash Cond: (r.a_id = b.a_id)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on r  (cost=0.00..35.95 rows=776 width=7) (actual time=0.024..1.120 rows=1198 loops=1)"
"                    Filter: (((q_id)::text = ANY ('{q1,q2,q3}'::text[])) OR ((q_id)::text = ANY ('{q4,q5,q6}'::text[])) OR ((q_id)::text = ANY ('{q7,q8,q9}'::text[])) OR ((q_id)::text = ANY ('{q10,q11,q12}'::text[])))"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=4.82..4.82 rows=3 width=14) (actual time=0.138..0.138 rows=3 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=2.41..4.82 rows=3 width=14) (actual time=0.057..0.135 rows=3 loops=1)"
"                          Hash Cond: (b.a_id = a.id)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on b  (cost=0.00..2.00 rows=100 width=8) (actual time=0.006..0.049 rows=100 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Hash  (cost=2.38..2.38 rows=3 width=6) (actual time=0.040..0.040 rows=3 loops=1)"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on a  (cost=0.00..2.38 rows=3 width=6) (actual time=0.008..0.035 rows=3 loops=1)"
"                                      Filter: (id = ANY ('{1,2,3}'::integer[]))"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=17.50..17.50 rows=3 width=72) (actual time=0.020..0.020 rows=1 loops=1)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on t  (cost=0.00..17.50 rows=3 width=72) (actual time=0.008..0.016 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                    Filter: ((session_id)::text = '1'::text)"
"Total runtime: 1.799 ms"
```

**PG 9.4, version 1**

```
"HashAggregate  (cost=63.54..63.55 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=11.393..11.394 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Group Key: t.id"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=19.96..63.54 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.223..11.387 rows=1 loops=1)"
"        Join Filter: ((b.a_id = r.a_id) AND ((t.q_id)::text = (r.q_id)::text))"
"        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 1155"
"        ->  Hash Join  (cost=19.96..22.72 rows=1 width=44) (actual time=0.202..0.294 rows=34 loops=1)"
"              Hash Cond: ((b.a_id = a.id) AND (b.study_id = t.study_id))"
"              ->  Seq Scan on b  (cost=0.00..2.00 rows=100 width=8) (actual time=0.016..0.030 rows=100 loops=1)"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=19.93..19.93 rows=2 width=44) (actual time=0.174..0.174 rows=34 loops=1)"
"                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2kB"
"                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=17.54..19.93 rows=2 width=44) (actual time=0.079..0.155 rows=34 loops=1)"
"                          Hash Cond: ((a.inst_id)::text = (t.inst_id)::text)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on a  (cost=0.00..2.00 rows=100 width=6) (actual time=0.007..0.026 rows=100 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Hash  (cost=17.50..17.50 rows=3 width=72) (actual time=0.025..0.025 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on t  (cost=0.00..17.50 rows=3 width=72) (actual time=0.012..0.021 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                      Filter: ((session_id)::text = '1'::text)"
"                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 35"
"        ->  Seq Scan on r  (cost=0.00..40.44 rows=25 width=7) (actual time=0.008..0.314 rows=34 loops=34)"
"              Filter: ((a_id = ANY ('{1,2,3}'::integer[])) AND (((q_id)::text = ANY ('{q1,q2,q3}'::text[])) OR ((q_id)::text = ANY ('{q4,q5,q6}'::text[])) OR ((q_id)::text = ANY ('{q7,q8,q9}'::text[])) OR ((q_id)::text = ANY ('{q10,q11,q12}'::text[]))))"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 1164"
"Planning time: 0.856 ms"
"Execution time: 11.499 ms"
```

**PG 9.4, version 2**

```
"HashAggregate  (cost=62.23..62.24 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=2.197..2.197 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Group Key: t.id"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=19.95..62.22 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.193..2.189 rows=1 loops=1)"
"        Join Filter: ((b.a_id = r.a_id) AND ((a.inst_id)::text = (t.inst_id)::text) AND (b.study_id = t.study_id))"
"        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 299"
"        ->  Hash Join  (cost=17.54..56.68 rows=12 width=44) (actual time=0.065..1.761 rows=100 loops=1)"
"              Hash Cond: ((r.q_id)::text = (t.q_id)::text)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on r  (cost=0.00..35.95 rows=819 width=7) (actual time=0.030..1.271 rows=1198 loops=1)"
"                    Filter: (((q_id)::text = ANY ('{q1,q2,q3}'::text[])) OR ((q_id)::text = ANY ('{q4,q5,q6}'::text[])) OR ((q_id)::text = ANY ('{q7,q8,q9}'::text[])) OR ((q_id)::text = ANY ('{q10,q11,q12}'::text[])))"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=17.50..17.50 rows=3 width=72) (actual time=0.022..0.022 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on t  (cost=0.00..17.50 rows=3 width=72) (actual time=0.008..0.018 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                          Filter: ((session_id)::text = '1'::text)"
"                          Rows Removed by Filter: 35"
"        ->  Materialize  (cost=2.41..4.83 rows=3 width=14) (actual time=0.001..0.003 rows=3 loops=100)"
"              ->  Hash Join  (cost=2.41..4.82 rows=3 width=14) (actual time=0.119..0.172 rows=3 loops=1)"
"                    Hash Cond: (b.a_id = a.id)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on b  (cost=0.00..2.00 rows=100 width=8) (actual time=0.007..0.028 rows=100 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=2.38..2.38 rows=3 width=6) (actual time=0.064..0.064 rows=3 loops=1)"
"                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on a  (cost=0.00..2.38 rows=3 width=6) (actual time=0.016..0.058 rows=3 loops=1)"
"                                Filter: (id = ANY ('{1,2,3}'::integer[]))"
"                                Rows Removed by Filter: 97"
"Planning time: 0.979 ms"
"Execution time: 2.309 ms"
```

## Update

I want to be clear that I really appreciate the tuning and data modeling advice that has been offered. However, this example is a simplification of a system-wide problem, and we are hoping to identify a way to bring performance back up to where it was before upgrading to PG9.4 without modifying our existing schema. Hopefully that is not possible.

Comment: What are the table definitions and indexes? Is `session_id` not covered with index (as its left-most part)?

Comment: "Why does changing the WHERE clause to reference a.id, instead of r.a_id modify the query plan so significantly?" --- because postgresql decides to join in different order.

Comment: Did you `analyze` all tables after the upgrade?

Comment: Check http://explain.depesz.com/s/cHq to see what is going wrong and where most time is spend: 34 sequential scans on the same table... And what about the rest of your database configuration? What are the differences for postgresql.conf between 8.4 and 9.4 ?

Comment: are `r.a_id ` and `a.id` both NOT NULLable? ( I expect to be `r.a_id` to be NULLable, since it appears to be a foreign key) ALSO did you run `VACUUM ANALYZE on the 9.4 installation?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses.
@zerkms: The table definitions can be found in the [document](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2I7_NGvCSVOT3ZNNWhpeFdFbTg/view?usp=sharing) linked at the top of the question. There are no indexes involved here to keep the example as simple as possible.
@zerkms: I guess the better question is: why is PG 9.4 choosing a much slower query plan for `version 1`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:
I did not run analyze on either DB after creating these **example** tables. The schema used in this example was built in each database immediately before running the queries (it was not imported from 8.4 to 9.4). I will try running analyze in each DB and post the results.

Comment: @joop: All columns involved are `NOT NULL`able (see the schema construction sql [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2I7_NGvCSVOT3ZNNWhpeFdFbTg/view?usp=sharing). However, no foreign keys were constructed in the sample schema. I assumed that PG's planner would figure it out based on the `JOIN` criteria. 

Finally, I did not run `VACUUM ANALYZE` on either DB after setting up the sample schema referenced in this post. I will re-run the queries after a VACUUM ANALYZE and post the results.

Comment: @FrankHeikens: Both databases are configured exactly the same, except for configuration options that are not available in PG8.4 (e.g. `dynamic_shared_memory_type`, and `huge_pages`). I will add a more thorough diff to the post later today. Thanks for showing me explain.depesz.com/s/cHq. It certainly makes reading the explain plans easier. While the query planner computed the costs to be almost the same in PG 9.4 and 8.4, the time taken is obviously much greater in 9.4. The most time consuming step in the 9.4 plan is the `Nested Loop` on line 3.  Any suggestions for tuning that out?

Comment: `I assumed that PG's planner would figure it out based on the JOIN criteria.` You assumptions are wrong. indexes (and so FKs / PKs) are weighted heavily, especially since the contributing columns will have statistics present. Having indexes (and statistics) normally causes the lower nodes to be (bitmap)index scans, and the parent nodes merging them. Also, having indexes allows the planner to pull the jointree *inside out*. BTW wrt tuning, I would try lowering random_page_cost to circa 2.

Comment: BTW: it makes little sense benchmarking small queries (1 .. 10 msec) like this. Often, only one disk page per table will (assumed to) be needed, and the planner will favorise seq scans if the tables happen to be small (and hash joins if the resultset is (expected to be) small)

Comment: I see no reason to benchmark futile queries over tables without any structure. OMHO the OP should do some basic training on data modelling.

Comment: @wildplasser: as mentioned above, this is intended to be a simple example, which avoids the complexity added by indexes, keys, etc... We are not looking to modify our data model, we are wondering why it performs so differently between PG 9.4 and 8.4, and how we might modify our PG 9.4 environment to achieve the same performance that we had in PG 8.4.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the query below is much simpler, at least to read.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT DISTINCT t.id
FROM t
INNER JOIN a ON a.inst_id = t.inst_id
INNER JOIN r ON r.a_id = a.id AND r.q_id = t.q_id
INNER JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id AND b.study_id = t.study_id
WHERE t.session_id = '1'
  AND r.a_id IN (1, 2, 3)
  AND r.q_id IN ('q1', 'q2', 'q3'
                ,'q4', 'q5', 'q6'
                ,'q7', 'q8', 'q9'
                ,'q10', 'q11', 'q12')
    ;
```

- adding `PRIMARY KEY` constraints for the serials will help a lot
- adding `FOREIGN KEY` constraits to the referring JOIN field (and `UNIQUE` constraints for the referrred fields) will help even more
- adding supporting indexes for the FKs completes the job
- that is: after running `VACUUM ANALYZE`
- BTW your data model seems to contain a loop. {study_id,inst_id} in tables {a,t,b} This could indicate redundancy (or a missed candidate key)
- your new machine seems to have a fast seek you could try lowering `random_page_cost` to about 2. Assuming that effective_cache_size and shared_buffers are sufficiently high. (but: *before tuning, get your data model into shape*)

Comment: Thanks @joop. Your example is clear and gives me some excellent ideas for modifying our schema. Unfortunately, we are not looking to optimize this query: we are wondering why the newer version of PG is choosing a vastly less efficient query plan. This example problem provided is just that: an example. We are having a systemic performance problem after upgrading to PG9.4, and are hoping for suggestions to help us identify the root cause.